# How to delete an object from an "Entity" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Excuse me for asking a simplistic question but I have just started with iOS programming. Below is my code to delete a row from a table (which works) and my attempt to delete the corresponding item from the associated entity ("TeamInfo") on which I am at a loss.

It is apparent that I have a lot to learn but in the meantime, can someone please help showing how to correct the code to delete the entity item.  I get the following error:

> Type TeamInfo.Type has no subscript members

on the line `moc.deleteObject(TeamInfo[indexPath.row])`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // 1
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // 2
        moc.deleteObject(TeamInfo(indexPath.row))

        appDelegate.saveContext()
        print (indexPath.row)

        // 4
        teamInfoArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `TeamInfo`? This is not a Core Data error, but a Swift syntax error from your attempted use of brackets `[`/`]` with TeamInfo.

Comment: You presumably have an array which contained your NSManagedObjects - You need to use this array rather than `TeamInfo` which is your object class.

Comment: You are attempting to use TeamInfo as an array but it isn't an array. Add the definition of TeamInfo.

Comment: Thank you.  It works by referencing the array as you all suggest.